# Deleting elements of a list based on a condition

Tags: python, list

I have a list of elements from which I want to remove those elements whose count is less than or equal to 2 in all the list.

For example:

```
A = [['a','b','c'],['b','d'],['c','d','e'],['c','e','f'],['b','c','e','g']]
```

I want to remove `'a'`, `'d'`, `'f'`, `'g'` from `A` and store the rest in `B` so that the list becomes:

```
B = [['b','c'],['b'],['c','e'],['c','e'],['b','c','e']]
```

I created a dictionary which will store all the count of elements and based on that I want to remove the elements with count less than or equal to 2.

Below is the code which I have written so far.

```
for i in range(len(A)):
    for words in A[i]:
        word_count[words] +=1
    B = [A[i] for i in range(len(A)) if word_count[words]<2]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
import itertools
A = [['a','b','c'],['b','d'],['c','d','e'],['c','e','f'],['b','c','e','g']]
c = Counter(itertools.chain(*A))
new_a = [[b for b in i if c[b] > 2] for i in A]
```

Output:

```
[['b', 'c'], ['b'], ['c', 'e'], ['c', 'e'], ['b', 'c', 'e']]
```

Comment: @BcK Thanks for the help. It is working for me. Also, in the same list instead of count if I want to store percentage in c and then select percentage greater than 40, how can I do that i.e. store percentage in c.

Comment: `total = sum(c.values()); for k, v in c.items(): c[k] = v / total` something like this should work @AnkitaPatnaik

Comment: This is an uncharacteristically good answer for a change and I have upvoted it. As an improvement, consider the use of `chain.from_iterable(A)` instead of `chain(*A)` as the former is more efficient.

Answer (score 4):

Before you add a new **key** to the **dictionary**, you have to check if the key **exists**. If not, just add the **key** to the **dictionary**. Otherwise, update the key's value.

```
A = [['a','b','c'],['b','d'],['c','d','e'],['c','e','f'],['b','c','e','g']]
word_count = {}
for i in range(len(A)):
  for words in A[i]:
    if words not in word_count:
      word_count[words] = 0
    word_count[words] += 1
```

Then filter the initial list using the created dictionary.

```
B = [[x for x in A[i] if word_count[x] > 2] for i in range(len(A))]
print(B)
```

Output

```
[['b', 'c'], ['b'], ['c', 'e'], ['c', 'e'], ['b', 'c', 'e']]
```

Comment: Little shortcut for `if words not in word_count: word_count[words] = 0` --> `word_count.setdefault(words, 0)`